# join replaces tabs by spaces

Tags: bash, join

I'm trying to join two `csv` files, sorted, and with tab delimiter.

I'm new to the `join` command, so I'm not too sure about how to use it, but it seems to be replacing every tab in the files with spaces (messing up the  alignment).

The command I'm using is:

```
join -1 5 -2 2 -t $'\t' -o $order --header file1.csv file2.csv | 
column -t > result.csv
```

In the first file, the data is sorted according to the *5th* column, and the *2nd* column in the second file.
The variable `$order` is a simple string containing the different columns *'1.1 1.2 1.3'* etc. (*28* of them).
The delimiter I'm using comes from SE.

Do you know where this comes from?

Comment: If the `$order` var is space separated, (rather than comma separated), it needs to be quoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because `column -t`, with the table mode automatically determines the column width and creates a readable table output and delimits output with *spaces* and not *tabs*.  To do this explicitly using `column`, use its output delimiter set flag with `-o`

```
join -1 5 -2 2 -t $'\t' -o $order --header file1.csv file2.csv | 
column -o '\t' > result.csv
```

Comment: thanks man, just unstuck me there

Comment: Why use `column` at all for this? Isn't it basically doing a `cat` here?

Answer (score 6):

The character used by `join` with `-t` as delimiter will be used for both input and output.

The issue is the post-processing step, `column -t`, that you use.  It will replace tabs with the appropriate number of spaces to align the columns nicely.  If you want to preserve the tabs in the output of `join`, don't pass the data through `column -t`.

Only use `column -t` for final (visual) presentation of tabulated data.